# Asus P8Z77-i Deluxe, cold boot issue

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

Alright, so when I turn on the computer, the DRAM LED lights up. The computer might restart once or twice, but not always. After a minute or two, if I restart the machine it will start up just fine.

If I power it back down, and power it up, it will be fine. If I shut it off for an hour (unplug from the wall et cetera) and power it back on, it will be fine.

If I shut it off overnight, and come back to turn it on it will give me the original error. (the last time i reproduced the error, it was off for 5 hours)

Components:

- ASUS P8Z77-I Deluxe LGA 1155 Intel Z77 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Mini ITX Intel Motherboard with USB BIOS
- Intel Core i5-3570K Ivy Bridge 3.4GHz (3.8GHz Turbo) LGA 1155 77W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I53570K
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL8D-8GBXM

Comment: This behavior new or has it always happen?  If its new I would replace the power suppl, if it always existed, I would return the motherboard.

Comment: The computer is a new build

Comment: That does not answer my question as I suggest replace the motherboard and powersupply

Comment: What's the _original error_ here?